# библиотека для голосового сообщения для c++

Tags: c++, аудио, library

Всем привет!
Я ищу хорошую и легкую библиотеку, которая работает с отправкой и получением голосового сообщения .wav-файла, можете ли вы поделиться своим опытом со мной, какую библиотеку выбрать, поскольку их много?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: под Вашу задачу попадает много библиотек и комбинаций, но они решают разные немного задачи. Может Вы приведете парочку библиотек, которые по Вашему мнению могут решить задачу, тогда Вам скорее всего набросают и других предложений.

Answer (score 2):

Весьма размытый вопрос у вас. И библиотека, вероятно, не одна понадобится.

> Я ищу хорошую и легкую библиотеку, которая работает с отправкой и получением голосового сообщения .wav-файла

Если данные отправляются и принимаются через Интернет, то, наверное, нужно использовать сжатие данных. То есть, обычно применяемое в файлах *.wav кодирование [PCM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F),  не подходит. Нужно использовать [кодеки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA) типа MP3, например, библиотеку [Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net). Или кодек [GSM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM-EFR).

Потом, если обмен через интернет, то может пригодиться библиотека [OpenSSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL), чтобы организовать защищенный канал.

Потом, частоту дискретизации сигнала, возможно, понадобится ограничить до 8кГц, для этого можно использовать [Sinc-фильтр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80), для реализации которого понадобится [БПФ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5), для реализации которого можно использовать библиотеку [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org).